# How do I call the Count method on an Entity Framework Context by using Reflection?

Tags: entity-framework

I'm trying to get count of records of each table by using the following code. But it doesn't work at all. GetMethod("Count") returns always null. I might do really stupid thing though, I don't know what to do.

```
var list = new List<TableInfoContainer>
{
    new TableInfoContainer{ObjectSetPropertyName="table1"},
    new TableInfoContainer{ObjectSetPropertyName="table2"},
    new TableInfoContainer{ObjectSetPropertyName="table3"},
};

using (var context = new DBEntities())
{
    list.ForEach(x =>{
        var property = context.GetType().GetProperty(x.ObjectSetPropertyName);
        x.RecordCount = (int)typeof(IQueryable).GetMethod("Count").Invoke(property, null);
    });
}
```

Aany help would be appreciated!

Thanks,
yokyo

Comment: Count is actually an extension method on System.Linq.Queryable. However it's templated on the type so I don't know if you need to type it somehow before calling it.

Comment: Thank you for your comment, Rup. Hmmm, yeah you are right, it's the extension method. I was thinking of that that's why I cannot get it. I'll try what you mentioned.

Comment: I've had a quick look at this for interest's sake but couldn't get anywhere. You can see the method in `typeof(System.Linq.Queryable).GetMethods(BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.InvokeMethod | BindingFlags.Public);` and then `.MakeGenericMethod` but calling it I get "Late bound operations cannot be performed on types or methods for which ContainsGenericParameters is true." Sorry - back to work.

Comment: Thanks Rup, I reached the same point. Hmmm, seems it isn't possible to  get it worked.